# Show antd horizontal menu onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

In this first [example](https://ant.design/components/menu/) of `horizontal menu`, I want to change "Navigation Three - Submenu" to open `onClick` instead `onHover` and want to add toggle icon (up and down arrow) next to it as well.

[image]

Comment: The link you've placed from your example does not contain anything. Check the URL of the example because you have passed the start page of a new script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to implement your own menu using `Tabs` component.

Here is the idea of how it's done, you need to add animations on revealing the menu and switching the `up/down` arrows.

```js
<Tabs onTabClick={() => setShowMenu(prev => !prev)}>
  <Tabs.TabPane
    tab={
      <>
        <Icon type="setting" />
        Navigation Three - Submenu
        <Icon type={showMenu ? "up" : "down"} style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }} />
      </>
    }
  />
</Tabs>;
{
  showMenu && (
    <Menu>
      <Menu.ItemGroup title="Item 1">
        <Menu.Item key="setting:1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="setting:2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
      </Menu.ItemGroup>
      <Menu.ItemGroup title="Item 2">
        <Menu.Item key="setting:3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="setting:4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
      </Menu.ItemGroup>
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

[image]

Demo:

[image: Edit Q-56637369]

Comment: Thanks, Dennis for Quick Response, I am building this menu dynamically and want to know how we can add event listeners for that. here is the code example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/q-56637369-1xdji

Comment: It's out of the scope of the question, you should ask another question and feel free sending me a link (and accepting the answer)

Comment: here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760820/antd-horizontal-menu-onclick-issue